# What 's different about creating an instance of a variable?

Tags: c++

I was wondering what's the different between creating an object with  `Line().setLength(6.0);`
and 
`Line line; line.setLength(6.0);`
After compiling would the result will be the same or not?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Line {
   public:
      void setLength( double len );
      double getLength( void );
      Line();   // This is the constructor declaration
      ~Line();  // This is the destructor: declaration

   private:
      double length;
};

// Member functions definitions including constructor
Line::Line(void) {
   cout << "Object is being created" << endl;
}

Line::~Line(void) {
   cout << "Object is being deleted" << endl;
}

void Line::setLength( double len ) {
   length = len;
}

double Line::getLength( void ) {
   return length;
}

// Main function for the program
int main( ) {
   Line().setLength(6.0);

   Line line;
   line.setLength(6.0); 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself, *how will I ever use the `Line` made from `Line().setLength(6.0);`?*

Answer (score 0):

The result should always be the same. However `Line().setLength(6.0);` means that you can't change properties of the line in the future whereas by using `Line line; line.setLength(6.0);` you can access the variable `line` and therefore change properties of the line.

Comment: _The result should always be the same._ Well, there's one difference: In the 1st case - object is destroyed as soon as the statement is executed. In the 2nd case, however, the declared object is destroyed as soon as execution flow leaves the scope it is declared in.

Comment: Hi All Thank you so much